# Is there a way to pass multiple options in assert statement in testcafe?

Tags: javascript, java, testing, automation, testcafe

I need to pass multiple options in my assert statement. Below is the assert statement

await t.expect(methodName.tableInput.innerText).eql('' or '\n'); //this is incorrect

I need to check if its an empty value. However on jenkins it says '\n' needs to be passed but locally '\n' fails

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t pass multiple options in the [assert statement](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/assert.html). I suggest you use the following approach

```
 const text = await Selector(‘yourSelector’).innerText;
 await t.expect(text === ‘ ‘ || text === ‘\n’).ok( );
```